# C# Class with Event Handler on own Property / Binding Computed Value to Form

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling, garbage-collection

I'm working on a Windows Forms app in C# at the moment, and I have one implementation in a class that I'm uncertain about and want to know if this implementation is a bad idea, and what alternatives there are if it is.

The class in question implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface so that it can be bound to a form via a `BindingSource`. One of the properties is a `BindingList` which is used to allow the user to edit a list of strings. There is another computed property that returns a string value based on this list of strings. I have both properties decorated with the `[Bindable(true)]` attribute so that they can be bound into the form. However, when the list is updated, the value that is bound to the computed value is not updated on the form.

To resolve that, I added a line in the constructor to handle the `ListChanged` event in the `BindableList` property so that I can issue a `PropertyChanged` event indicating that the computed value has been changed as well. This works and the form updates as desired. However, having a class register an event listener on one of its own properties seems like a bad idea to me.

Would this prevent instances of this class from ever being disposed by the garbage collector? Or am I misunderstanding how the garbage collector would interact with event handlers? If this is not ideal, what would be a better way to bind a computed property to a form (particularly when the computed value is not just needed in this one form)? Or would it work fine if the class implements `IDisposable` and unregister the event handler in the `Dispose` method?

```cs
class BoundObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    
    [Bindable(true)]
    public readonly BindingList<StringHolder> Lines = new BindingList<StringHolder>();
    
    [Bindable(true)]
    public string ComputedProperty
    {
        get
        {
            // Compute value based on Lines
            return value;
        }
    }
    
    public BoundObject()
    {
        Lines.ListChanged += Lines_ListChanged;
    }
    
    private void Lines_ListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(ComputedProperty)));
    }
}
```

Comment: _" and want to know if this implementation is a bad idea, and what alternatives there are if it is"_ - then show code, don't write prose :) If you can make it a [mcve] that would be perfect. If that would be too much, then at least post enough relevant code so we have something to actually talk about.

Comment: It looks like implementing `IDisposable` is good enough here. Add a bool Field (e.g., `bool isDisposed = false`), check this value in `Dispose(bool disposing)` and remove the handler when `isDisposed = false`, set it to `true` after

Comment: @Fildor-standswithMods I've added a code snippet to exemplify the structure of the class in question.

Comment: @Jimi I think that makes sense, and I've implemented the IDispose interface.

Comment: Yep. Make a little test: put a breakpoint inside the `Dispose(bool disposing)` method. Call `Dispose()` in the first *test*, then call `Dispose()` and close the Parent Form in the second one, then do the same without calling `Dispose()` first. See when the Finalizer kicks in and the state of your object at that point (always make sure the object is not null and that you're not causing exceptions here). You could also verify what happens if you force Garbage Collection